# C++ Multiple new on single pointer

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm pretty sure this is a basic question, but I can't find the answer anywhere(maybe because of the wrong search terms).

Is the following code creating a memory leak?

```
int * ptr= new int(15);
ptr= new int(25);
```

Do I have to delete the first pointer before calling the `new` operator on the same pointer for a second time?

Comment: I can't believe someone hasn't already trotted out the old "never use `new`!" line. :)

Comment: You just didn't search hard enough, no offense :) Questions similar to this are asked almost every day on SO.

Comment: None taken. I was almost sure of the answer, but I tought there was maybe a mechanism that was overriding re-assignation of pointers like with `auto_ptr, unique_ptr, shared_ptr` mentioned below.

Comment: @Frank: There *is* a mechanism, and it involves using `unique_ptr`: `auto i = make_unique<int>(15); i = make_unique<int>(25);`. There. No resources lost :-)

Comment: Oh! Thanks @Kerrek SB, I didn't knew that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clear things up a little actually.
`New` will give you a "random" pointer from the heap and the only guarantee is that you can fit your requested amount of bytes into the block of memory your pointer points to.

Consider the following:

`int *x = new int;` Pointer `x` now points to say **0x12345678**, and there's a place for an integer there and the only way you can get to this integer is to use the address that's stored in your pointer `x`.

Now suppose you call new again. `x = new int;`  The integer room at **0x12345678** stays "reserved" for you yet your pointer now points elsewhere, say to **0x87654321** where there's been a new "spot" made for the new integer, and the pointer to the previous one is lost forever, since your pointer no longer points to the original part of the heap.

Solution to this problem would be calling `delete` on the pointer, which would NOT touch the pointer `x` itself, it would simply deallocate the memory from the heap that the pointer just happens to point to. (And as a direct result of that, the `x` itself would change but just because `new` would assign the value to it ...)

Now you can freely call `new` yet again.

(edit) Yes, `new` does call the constructor for you but that's not the point here really.

Comment: @JohnDibling Actually, OP doesn't care about the constructor for this particular question so I don't think it's relevant. I'll be enjoying my -1 though :)

Answer (score 5):

yes, you are over-writing `ptr` with another call to `new`. Hence the 1st pointer is lost.

If you want re-use the same variable `ptr` then just `delete` the 1st pointer and use it again safely.

Answer (score 5):

> Is the following code creating a memory leak?

Yes, it is.

> Do I have to delete the first pointer before calling the new operator on the same pointer for a second time?

Yes, you should `delete` anything allocated with `new` before you lost all references to it and no longer can free it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and yes. Every time you use `new`, you must use `delete`, it's counterpart.

Comment: Unless the result of `new` is assigned to an `auto_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, etc...

Comment: @RobI: For every call to new, there must be a corresponding call to delete.  Better?